# adding/removing z-index on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to add or remove the z-index property on two separate divs as the user hovers on them.

The catch is I have some Jquery written so it keeps the z-index property as the mouse is moved away, this is so there is a smooth transition. https://jsfiddle.net/45wdhdjy/1/

```
$(".w-1").one("mouseover", function() {
  $(".w-1").addClass('permahover');
});
```

My problem is after hovering over the blue div the yellow div fails to have a greater z-index on its hover. I have a feeling the solution is joining both of my scripts into one if statement but I'm unsure how to go about this. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: It would help if you explained what you are actually trying  to achieve here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well... i tried your code and this works in file js

```
$(".w-1").on("mouseover", function() {
    $(".w-2").removeClass('permahover2');
  $(".w-1").addClass('permahover');
});

$(".w-2").on("mouseover", function() {
  $(".w-2").addClass('permahover2');
  $(".w-1").removeClass('permahover');
});
```

for each event remove class the other div.

Comment: Thanks dude, easy solution. As you may be able to tell I really need to learn javascript. :)

Answer (score 3):

Just use the css, its better, cleaner:

```
.w-1{z-index:0;}
.w-1:hover{z-index:1000;}
```

of course I ignore other css styles the class might have. the class must also have a `position` style defined for it otherwise `z-index` won't work;

Considering the comments:
HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="work-1"></div><div class="work-2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 60%;
    transition: all ease 0.4s
}

.work-1, .work-2 {
    transition: all ease 0.4s;
    width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
display:inline-block;

}

.work-1 {
    background-color: #FEF102;
}

.work-2 {
    background-color: #4B3E7F;
}

.active{width:100%;}
.inactive{width:0%;}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('.wrapper div').mouseover(function(){
     $('.wrapper div').not($(this)).addClass('inactive');
     $(this).addClass('active');
}).mouseout(function(){
     $('.wrapper div').removeClass('active').removeClass('inactive');
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/45wdhdjy/2/)

Comment: I had this originally but z-index doesn't transition so it looked clunky when you un-hovered over the div. Thanks anyway.

Comment: what is you exact problem. tell me soI might be able to help

Comment: In the jsfiddle over over the yellow div, then the blue div then the yellow div again. You can see the second time round on the yellow div the z-index isn't great enough because the jquery changed the blue div. I'm hoping to join my two scripts into one which both adds/removes the z-index based on which div is hovered over. Hopefully this makes sense. (have to go out for an hour so excuse any late replies).

Comment: @MaxPower please have a look at this fiddle: [Your updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/45wdhdjy/2/)

Comment: I always feel bad for not marking the more detailed answer correct but I prefer Wilders answer because it maintains the width of the inactive div. Thanks for your time though :)

Answer (score 1):

Your mouseOver is fired only once. You should be able to do the effect by using on and removing the permahover on each div.

```
$(.w-2).removeClass('permahover2')
```

Before each call. Please see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/45wdhdjy/1/